# Difference between get_lines() method of axes and legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

In the code

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

fig1 = Figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
p1 = ax1.plot([1,2,3], label='123')
lg1 = ax1.legend()
```

`lg1.get_lines()[0] == ax1.get_lines()[0]` evaluates to false even though they should be referring to the same line. May I know why this is the case?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should add more details and attach some basic code. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I solved what I originally wanted to do, so I changed the question to the part that I still can't figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that they are different instances of objects in memory.

```
In [6]: lg1.get_lines()
Out[6]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10e355828>]

In [7]: ax1.get_lines()
Out[7]: <a list of 1 Line2D objects>

In [8]: list(ax1.get_lines())
Out[8]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10e342940>]
```

Notice that the id values are different, therefore, they are not truly "equal", even though they may "refer" to the same object in the plot.

```
In [9]: lg1.get_lines()[0]
Out[9]: <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10e355828>

In [10]: ax1.get_lines()[0]
Out[10]: <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10e342940>
```

```
In [11]: id(lg1.get_lines()[0])
Out[11]: 4533344296

In [12]: id(ax1.get_lines()[0])
Out[12]: 4533266752
```

Or, rather, `ax1.get_lines()` gives the line that is plotted and `lg1.get_lines()` gives the actual lines drawn in the legend box

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just realised that `ax1.get_lines()` gives the line that is plotted and `lg1.get_lines()` gives the actual lines drawn in the legend box. So they are totally different objects.